# How to do Dynamic port forwarding with libssh2?

Tags: ssh, ios, objective-c

I want to implement dynamic port forwarding in my iOS(objective c)application.

I have done local and remote port forwarding using libssh2 library. I think this library only gives local and remote port forwarding feature.

Can anyone suggest how to do dynamic port forwarding with this library or any other which gives this functionality?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At SSH level they're the same thing. There is **no difference** protocol-wise between "local" and "dynamic" forwarding – both of them result in a `direct-tcpip` channel being opened for each new connection (which in libssh2 is done using the ssh_channel_open_forward() function).

In both cases, the client app listens on a TCP port, and whenever it receives a connection it creates a 'direct-tcpip' channel over SSH and copies data back-and-forth.

The only difference is user-facing behavior, and that's implemented entirely in the SSH app itself:

- In "local" forwarding, the SSH client has the destination host:port preconfigured, and it always opens direct-tcpip channels to that specific destination.
- In "dynamic" forwarding, the SSH client speaks the SOCKS5 protocol to dynamically determine what host:port to connect to.

So if you only need to open 'forwarded' connections internally (for the app's own purposes), then just use ssh_channel_open_forward() and you can read/write directly from that channel.

And if you want to accept SOCKS5 clients like "ssh -D" does, then *your app* needs to handle the whole "SOCKS5 server" part. That's not something the SSH library knows or cares about.

Comment: Thank you @user1686 for the answer. It is really helpful. can you suggest how to do "ssh -D" and how to handle "SOCKS5 server" part? I am new to this.

Comment: can you suggest how to do "ssh -D" and how to handle "SOCKS5 server"? @user1686

Comment: Dynamic port forwarding = Local port forwarding + SOCKS Proxy